# how to check if value exists from value?

Tags: javascript, math

if I have the following values

```
0 - a
1 - b
2 - c
4 - d
8 - e
16 - f
```

if i get the value 17, how would i know that values b and f are in that values, some for the others as these can be mixed together by adding, so bd value would be 6

Comment: based on your info bd === 5. What do you receive as input and what output expect?

Comment: That "a" is `0` is kind of odd, that means it's in every value. Are you sure about that?

Comment: you can use this too:

    function find(target, obj, duplicate = true) {
      const keys = Object.keys(obj);
      let res = [];
      for (let n = 0; n < keys.length; n++) for (let m = duplicate ? 0 : n; m < keys.length; m++) if (obj[keys[n]] + obj[keys[m]] === target) res.push(keys[n]+keys[m]);
      return res;
    }
    console.log(find(17, { a: 0, b: 1, c: 2, d: 4, e: 8, f: 16 }));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your value to binary format. For example 17 => 10001. Then select only 1's. You can make for loop starts from 'a' to 'z'. Increase characters +1 then convert to character.

This is sample code:

```
function foo(num) {
  if (num == 0)
    return 'a';

  const binaryNum = (num >>> 0).toString(2);

  function nextChar(c) {
      return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
  }

  var converted = '';
  var asci = 'b';
  for(var i=binaryNum.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
      if (binaryNum.charAt(i) == '1')
          converted+=asci;
      asci = nextChar(asci);
  }
  return converted;
}

console.log(foo(17));
console.log(foo(0));
console.log(foo(6));
console.log(foo(28));
```

Output is:

```
bf
a
bd
def
```

Note that 'bd' is 5.

Answer (score 1):

Much like the bank note problem, reduce down the value in denominations, then pick out the index for the map to the letter.

```js
const v1 = [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16];
const v2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
let value = 7

const vMap = new Map();
for (let i = v1.length - 1; i >= 0 && value; i--) {
  const qty = Math.floor(value / v1[i]);
  qty && vMap.set(v1[i], qty);
  value = value % v1[i];
}

const entries = Array.from(vMap.entries());

console.log(entries.map(([curr, qty]) => `${curr} * ${qty} = ${curr * qty} is ${v2[v1.indexOf(curr)]}`))
```